# Sharing access to partner community users based on record owner

Tags: sharing, community, apex-managed-sharing, partner-communities

Im trying to write what feels like it should be a simple Apex sharing rule but not having much luck.

Basically I want partner users to be able to see all "customers" (custom object) owned by customer community users within the same account. The communities sharing set settings allow me to automatically share customers with other customer community users but not partner community users.  So i'm trying to setup a apex trigger to create sharing rules for all the partner community users within the same account.

When I edit a customer i'm getting this error:

**Apex trigger shareCustomer caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: shareCustomer: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []: Trigger.shareCustomer: line 22, column 1**

line 22 being the insert statement

and here is my code!

```
trigger shareCustomer on Customer__c (after insert, after update) {

    List<Customer__Share> customerShares  = new List<Customer__Share>();
    Customer__Share customerShare;

    for(Customer__c customer : trigger.new){
        list<User> users = [ Select Id from User where accountId = :customer.Organization_Id__c and profileId = '00eG0000000ycc8IAA' and isActive = true];

        for (User u: users) {

                customerShare = new Customer__Share();
                customerShare.ParentId = customer.Id;
                customerShare.UserOrGroupId = u.Id;
                customerShare.AccessLevel = 'edit';
                customerShare.RowCause = Schema.Customer__Share.RowCause.Organization__c;
                customerShares.add(customerShare);


        }
    }

    Database.SaveResult[] lsr = Database.insert(customerShares);

}
```

here is a simple diagram of the relationships im trying to get through:

[image]

UPDATE:  Some of the responders seem to be getting confused because the data in question is "customers"  what i've done is try and write a reusable class that could share any data, with any partner accounts roles..  but STILL not working, getting the same error as above.

```
public static void shareWithAccount(Id parentId, Id accountId) {

        List<Customer__Share> customerShares  = new List<Customer__Share>();
        Customer__Share customerShare;

        list<UserRole> roles = [ SELECT Name, Id FROM UserRole where PortalAccountId  = :accountId];

        string roleID;
        for (UserRole role: roles) {

           try {
            Group g = [select Id from group where RelatedId = :role.Id and type='Role' limit 1]; 

            customerShare = new Customer__Share();
            customerShare.ParentId = parentId;
            customerShare.UserOrGroupId = g.Id;
            customerShare.AccessLevel = 'edit';
            customerShare.RowCause = Schema.Customer__Share.RowCause.Organization__c;
            customerShares.add(customerShare);

           } catch (exception e) {

           }


        }



        if (!customerShares.isEmpty())
            Database.SaveResult[] customerSharesResult = Database.insert(customerShares);


    }
```

Comment: Hi Keith, Im sure someone will point this out in their answer: avoid SOQL in loops as you will hit a governor limits very. In this case you have a few nested for loops with SOQL queries which will hit the 101 SOQL limit very quickly.

Comment: For sure, im just trying to get it working then i can refactor to avoid SOQL in the loops

Comment: Also make sure that the user you are selecting isActive. This may cause the error you are seeing.

Comment: hmm added isActive check and still failing.  I should have mentioned customer.Organization_Id__c is a formula field that just gets the ORG id from the owner... so im getting all the contacts at that org and trying to find users for each

Comment: What line in your code is the cross-ref error? You may need to remove your try/catch block to get the right line.

Comment: Cleaned up the code example and error message... basically the error is on the insert statement.  Any advice you might have would be a HUGE help!

Comment: You could try moving the creation of the share record to a helper class/method, even trying @future.

Comment: i tried that too... even added @future.  No error then but it never saves the share...ugh

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update 03-11-16**

Two important revisions to communities have occurred since I wrote this answer that should be considered. First is that User Sharing and visibility restrictions on the User Object in an Org are now in place (SU 15 as I recall). This impacts SF Users visibility to other users both inside an Org and within an Org's Customer Community.

The 2nd one is the introduction of Customer Community Plus licenses. These licenses DO NOT have the same sharing model as regular Customer Communities. That sharing is vastly different. However, Customer Community Plus licenses support Managed Apex Sharing which is often the only way in which records can be shared. Sharing groups are not available as they are with regular Customer Communities. Please keep this in mind when reading this answer.

**EDIT 3**

I just found this: "You can share a standard or custom object with users or groups. **Apex sharing is not available for Customer Community users**." on the following page http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm. I think that's the definitive answer regarding Apex Sharing with Community Users. You'll need to either change owners or set up a sharing group.

**EDIT 2**

I'd gotten that the customer wasn't a contact, but that the Portal User was. You still need to get the `Owner` of the `Portal User.contact` to set up your sharing if you're going to do it by `User`. Remember: **Portal Users do not have a Role.** You're not going to be able to do any kind of role based sharing unless you do it as a child of the `Owner`.

Your idea of transferring ownership to the system admin has a lot of merit, especially if the Portal User doesn't need to retain ownership and only needs to be able to view the record. That would likely be the simplest solution to your problem.

**EDIT 1**

I've edited my post to included some of my comments below and try to clarify them rather than create a long back and forth thread.

Fist, depending on your actual schema, I believe the above query should retrieve the Owner's ID and UserRoleId, not the Portal User's RoleId provided the contact__c object is the same as the contact object.

Since both Owners who have SF Licenses and Portal Users that have Communities licenses are **all** Users, in theory, you could get them all in one query. You can also do them as two separate queries. How best to do them depends on what info you need and whether one depends on the other. Its also a matter of what method you're most comfortable with.

The Owner(**a SF User**) owns the Contact and the Account associated with the Contact, but **not** the Communities User. To be clear, a Communities User **cannot** own another Contact nor an Account simply because they don't have anything other than read access to those objects for their own information (both contact and account)!

However any kind of User can be retrieved via a query on User. Additionally, a User's Contact info can be retrieved by a query on User (contact = User.contact.Id, contact.Name = User.contact.Name, etc.).

You say below that the Owner of the contact for the Portal User is also a Portal User, the question I'd have is what license that Portal User has? It can't be a Communities License.

If this helps, here's how Communities Users are created using Apex:

```
Account> a = new Account(Name = Acme ); 
/* OwnerID will either be specified or will be ID of User who performs this operation.*/
insert a;

Contact c = new Contact(FirstName = John, LastName = Doe, Account = a[0].Id (ID of Ajax Acct), email = test@salesforce.stackexchangetest.com, Phone = 800-555-1212, MailingStreet = .....); 
/* you know the drill for the rest of the data required. */
/* Again, the OwnerID is for the User who performs the operation unless an OwnerID is specified */
insert c;

User u =new User(ContactID = c[0].Id (John Doe's contact.Id), Alias = 'PrtlUsr1', Email= c[0].Email, FirstName= c[0].FirstName, LastName= c[0].LastName, userName=c[0].Email, ProfileID = CommunitiesLicenceID for your org);
/* Again, the OwnerID is for the User who performs the operation unless an OwnerID is specified */
Insert u;
```

In my experience, it requires a SF User license to create a Portal User.

> The owner of the customer is a portal user tho, i guess thats what im
>   not understanding. Are you saying is should be getting the portal user
>   -> Contact -> and that owner? how does that help when what im trying to share is the "customer" I think people are getting confused because
>   they are called "customers" but they are just a custom object.

This could very well be the "disconnect" that's been occurring. Since there is no "role hierarchy", yes, you need to be retrieving the `Portal User Contact` and the `Owner` of the `Portal User Contact` in order to share anything that belongs to the `Portal User`. Why? Because the only other person that can see everything the `Portal User "owns"` is the `Owner` of the `Portal User Contact` -> (Portal) `User.contact.OwnerID`!

The only other way that immediately comes to mind that might help you accomplish what you desire would be to utilize your trigger to add these Users to a Sharing Group of some kind; something you might also want to consider as an alternative.

I hope this provides the clarification you needed in order to help you move forward with your trigger.

BTW, when you do your test class, I recommend you utilize "Run As" when you create your `Account, Contact and Portal User`. That will automatically create the `Portal User` with the `Run As` `User` as it's `Owner`.

**Original Answer**

Communities `Users` have an `Owner`. They do **not** have a `Role`, all they have is a `User Profile`. Essentially, they ***quasi inherit*** their `Role` from their `Owner`. Their Owner can see any of the records they create. So, if you want to share something a `Communities User` "owns", you're going to need to do that through their `Owner`.

```
trigger shareCustomer on Customer__c (after insert, after update) {

   List<Customer__Share> customerShares  = new List<Customer__Share>();
   Customer__Share customerShare;
```

I agree with Greenstork, you need the `User Role Id` from `related Owners (Users)` in the trigger set. Now the question is:

Are your customers logging in as `Communities Users` or as `Customers (Contacts)`?

If as `Users`, then your query may need to reflect that. Your query currently shows as `Customer__c`, which is a Custom Object. Is there a relationship between `Customer__c` and either `Contacts` or `Communities Users`?

```
List<Customer__c> enhancedCustomerList = [SELECT id, Owner.UserRoleId, OwnerID FROM Customer__c WHERE id IN :trigger.new];
```

If there is, you may want to utilize that relationship in your trigger. That's for you to decide. I primarily say that because it may simplify things for you because of `Ownership` when it comes to `Communities Users`.

The rest of your trigger would look pretty much the same as what Greenstork has shown depending on the relationships you use between `contact, account, Portal User, and Portal User.OwnerID`. The sharing is going to occur based on the `Owner` of `contact/customer__c/Portal User`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the information.  Customers is a custom object, and the relationship with the Communities Users is through record ownership, they create and own the customers (note: customers don't every log in, its just a custom object).  They are logging as communities users to a Force.com site and creating the customer records (among other things).

Comment: So my question for you is your query is pulling the Owner.UserRoleId which would bull the Communities users roleID which is blank.  What you are saying is i need to get the owner, then in another query get THAT users owner and share things through that?

Comment: Depending on your actual schema, I believe the above query should retrieve the Owner's ID and UserRoleId, not the Portal User's RoleId. Since they're all Users, in theory, you could get them all in one query or you can do them as two separate queries if you need all the info. Its a matter of what method you're most comfortable with. The Owner(a SF User) owns the contact, not the Communities User (contact = User.contact.Id). However both kinds of Users can be retrieved via a query on User.

Comment: The owner of the customer is a portal user tho, i guess thats what im not understanding.  Are you saying is should be getting the portal user -> Contact -> and that owner?  how does that help when what im trying to share is the "customer"  I think people are getting confused because they are called "customers" but they are just a custom object.

Comment: See my edited answer that addresses all of your comments

Comment: I feel like your still missing the key issue here... the Communities user is creating data and they own the data, that data i want to share with partners commmunity users in the same account.  They key here is the owner of the data is a communities user and the data to be share is a custom object (customers) "customers" in this context are just a custom object, customers dont have user accounts.  For our purposes you might as well just call them widgets..

Comment: All that matters here is when im creating the customer share record what do i set the parent id and the usergroupid to customerShare = new Customer__Share();
customerShare.ParentId = customer.Id;
                customerShare.UserOrGroupId = u.Id;

Comment: Check out my edits above... created an abstracted "shareWithAccount" glass trying to create customerShare records and still getting the same error??

Comment: Hey, the bounty period was over so I awarded it to you because you've gotten me the closest to the answer.  If there's anyway you can tell me what's wrong with the method I wrote in my latest edit I'd really appreciate it.   Seems to me that it is correct but it's just not possible to share content owned by community members, maybe I need to write a different trigger to transfer ownership to the system admin first?

Comment: Sorry that with Thanksgiving I wasn't able to respond to your additional comments. I didn't offer my help for the points, but thank you for them anyway. Greenstork certainly helped get you down the road a bit too since I started from where he'd left off. I know you can only award points to one of us but just wanted to acknowledge that since he's a very helpful guy around here who's a great asset to the community.

Comment: Completely agree, thank you both so much for all your help.  I know we are close, but it's still not working.  If I change the objects owner to system admin them the method works perfectly.  So it seems that it's just not possible to share content owned by customer community members with partner community members?

Comment: Did you see my **Edit 2** comments in my Answer above? I think I addressed your questions in those remarks. I hope they point you towards success. :)

Comment: In not sure how that changes my code?  I'm trying to add a share to share the content owned by customer community's user.  It seems like the solution is that, that just isn't possible.  That I have to change the owner?

Comment: I just found this: "You can share a standard or custom object with users or groups. Apex sharing is not available for Customer Community users." on the following page http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm. I think that's the definitive answer regarding Apex Sharing with Community Users. You'll need to either change owners or set up a sharing group.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: This answer was given prior to the OP making it clear that the owner of the Customer__c records was a customer community user and not a partner community user.

In the case of partner community users, the role of the record owner is shared by all users with the same account. Instead of trying to create share records for each user, consider just sharing to that role, which is unique by all accounts. That is to say, there is no danger of sharing across accounts since roles are unique for each partner.

Also, as a side note, your code is far from bulk safe. You have SOQL statements inside two for loops and this could lead to big problems with bulk DML operations on the Customer__c object.

Try this instead:

```
trigger shareCustomer on Customer__c (after insert, after update) {

    List<Customer__Share> customerShares  = new List<Customer__Share>();
    Customer__Share customerShare;

    //you need the User Role Id from related owners (users) in the trigger set
    List<Customer__c> enhancedCustomerList = [SELECT id, Owner.UserRoleId FROM Customer__c WHERE id IN :trigger.new];

    for(Customer__c customer : enhancedCustomerList){

        customerShare = new Customer__Share();
        customerShare.ParentId = customer.Id;
        customerShare.UserOrGroupId = customer.Owner.UserRoleId;
        customerShare.AccessLevel = 'edit';

        customerShares.add(customerShare);
    }

    try {
        Database.SaveResult[] lsr = Database.insert(customerShares,false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //handle your exception
    }

}
```

What's not included here and you might consider is some cleanup code to remove shares when record ownership changes. I also don't remember what happens when you try to create a share record when it already exists.

Comment: Hmm this is helpful... but the role thing wont work because the records are "owned" by customer community users and i want to share them with partner community users.  To the partner community user will have a role, but the customer community wont?

Comment: You may want to update your question to explicitly state that. I was under the impression that you were asking about partner community users sharing with each other. That is how both the title of this post and question reads.

Comment: Customer Community users do not have access to the sharing model, nor are they directly associated with an account. Their contact of course, is associated with an account but the user is not.

Comment: That is to say, I'm not sure Customer Communities users are allowed to create sharing records

Comment: right... thats part of the problem.  Im open to other approaches?