# How to share External Account, Contacts, Custom Object Records for Partner User in Communities

Tags: sharing, community, partner-communities, partner

Is it possible to share the external Accounts to a Partner Enabled Account User(Partner Account -> Contact (Partner User)) ?

The Scenario is something like this:
 I have Account, Opportunity etc. from various regions(e.g. Region A, Region B, Region C..& so on), so what I did is for sharing among Standard Salesforce User's; I made OWD settings as **private** and then share the records among different User(various regions) as per *Roles & Subordinate* defined for them and with a field say *Region* in Accounts, related Opportunities etc with the help of Sharing Rules.

 
Now the difficulty comes here when **Communities** came into existence & **Partner User's**(External User's - I am NOT referring PARTNER PORTAL here).
As we know that when we create Partner User's from contact's they are being assigned to one of the three profiles:

1. (Account Name appended) + Partner Executive.

2. (Account Name appended) + Partner Manager.

3. (Account Name appended) + Partner User.

so in this case how will I share the Account's of an External Entity(business) to my Partner User's that required to access it (e.g. Scenario: Like this partner user is my star salesman & i wanted him to work on multiple accounts or I want to give access to my Partner User to be able to approach existing accounts for his region's); Because for every *Partner-user* I create may belong to different Accounts and accordingly he has a unique name with Account names prefix as mentioned above.

So I am looking here for an Approach through which I would share the Accounts already existing in my ORG to Community User's *or* Partner User's)

Answer (score 0):

Since we are not talking about partner portal, I do not believe that others have access to accounts they are not members of.

You could do it in visualforce but not through the standard layouts.

Comment: But there must be a way to do that...as making communities in place of partner portal doesn't seems to be restricted in this way. And also logically there is no way to make communities only just to share single records with partner user's.

Comment: Could anything from this post help you out? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20894/sharing-access-to-partner-community-users-based-on-record-owner

Comment: Yesterday I was doing some analysis on this and I found that in our org we have given Default account owner to one person that is in the top of Role Hierarchy, and the External partner user should lie just below that role only so he must be able to see all the records of Account object & partner user are able to access all account records but in the list view 'All Accounts' why partner user not able to see all accessible records.